# How to add an attribute to User reference

Tags: 7, users, entities

I would need to add an attribute to a user_reference field that "explains" the type of relationship.

Example:
My users are music players and the play in different groups.
The same user can play guitar in one group and the bass in another group.

Groups are my nodes and I can link them with the players. While I am linking them, I would also like to set the instruments they play in that group.

Group 1 - Player1|guitar
Group 2 - Player1|bass
Group 3 - Player2|guitar

Probably a way to do that is using "field collection"; is there another way?

Comment: What is wrong with field collection? I think it's the best way to do this.

Comment: I don't really like field collection. In the past it happened to me that I had some problem with views and other modules. Consequently usually I try to avoid it.

Comment: @Huelfe I agree. The alternative is to create a node bundle for relationship using fields: user, instrument, groups and pull that in but that is very cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives could be [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs), [Multifield](https://drupal.org/project/multifield), [Inline Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) or [Double Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/double_field).

Comment: Why these? Please provide more info.